# List of api available for black berry os 5.0

Tags: blackberry

I need to develop app for black berry os version 4.6 and 5.0,i am developing on black berry jre 6.0, so i need to know which api is availble for os5.0 and also for os 4.6

Answer (score 2):

- [BB API 4.6](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/index.html)
- [BB API 5.0](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html)

Also in API docs you should pay attention to **Since x.x** statements.

Answer (score 1):

Hey. Have you taken a look at "[Documentation for Developers](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/?userType=21)" on blackberry.com?

Or the [Java Development](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/tkb-p/java_dev@tkb) section of the support forums?

It has sample apps for java, and visual studio (web development), and a full list of api references that you should required.

Good luck